# dynamoose search using GSI returns Index can't be found for query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

Here's my dynamoose schema for table `seller`

```
const schema = new dynamoose.Schema({
    PK: {
        type: String,   //ni letak emel.toLowerCase() + #main/business/delivery/ehailing
        hashKey: true,
    },
    SK: {        
        type: String,  
        rangeKey: true,
        "index": {  //utk 'auto' display kedai bila user ada kat location tu
            "name": "SKIndex",
            "global": true,
            "rangeKey": "location"
        }
    },
    "location": String,
}, {
    "saveUnknown": true,
    "timestamps": true
});
```

As you can see above, I created a GSI with the `SK` as the hashkey named `SKIndex` and having `location` as the rangeKey. So I tried to perform the query below

```
var SKIndex_search = "some value"
var locality = "some value too"
var filter = new dynamoose.Condition().where("SKIndex").eq(SKIndex_search).filter("location").beginsWith(locality);
var getResult = await Seller.query(filter).exec()
```

but it will always return the error `"InvalidParameter: Index can't be found for query."`

==============
When running this query `Seller.query(SKIndex_search).using("SKIndex").filter("location").beginsWith(locality).exec()`

It will display the error message `ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element`

Full error log:

```
aws:dynamodb:describeTable:response - {
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "PK",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "SK",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "location",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "earthlings_seller",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "PK",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "SK",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": "2021-06-26T20:50:13.233Z",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 312,
        "ItemCount": 1,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/earthlings_seller",
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
            {
                "IndexName": "SKIndex",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "SK",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "location",
                        "KeyType": "RANGE"
                    }
                ],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
                },
                "IndexSizeBytes": 312,
                "ItemCount": 1,
                "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/earthlings_seller/index/SKIndex"
            }
        ]
    }
}
aws:dynamodb:query:request - {
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#qra": "location"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":qrv": {
            "S": "nilai"
        }
    },
    "TableName": "earthlings_seller",
    "IndexName": "SKIndex",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "begins_with (#qra, :qrv)"
}
```

Comment: `where` accepts a property name (`SK`) not an index name (`SKIndex`). You can use the `using` method to set an index name. But if you change your condition to use `where("SK")` it should work.

Comment: changing it to `where("SK")` works, thanks! So behind-the-scene, dynamoose/dynamodb will try to determine by itself if the given property name in the query is the 'primary' index or global index? Anyway I also tried the `using` method with `Seller.query(SKIndex_search).using("SKIndex").filter("location").beginsWith(locality).exec()`  but I will receive this error `ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element`

Comment: What is `SKIndex_search` set to?

Comment: @CharlieFish `SKIndex_search` is just a value supplied by the user, in this case it's a country code of  the user, for eg, `my`, `au`

Comment: Tough to say then without more details then. That error looks to be an AWS error tho. So my guess is for some reason the request being sent is invalid. You can try to use `dynamoose.logger.providers.add(console);` (https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Dynamoose#dynamooseloggerprovidersaddprovider) to add logging for Dynamoose and see what request is being sent. That might give a hint as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CharlieFish. I added the output log in the question above after I added the line `dynamoose.logger.providers.add(console);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234268/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-imin).

Comment: It sounds like `SKIndex_search` is the value. But you never specify what the attribute name is. Remember, every query is key value pairs. You set `"location"=locality`, but you set `____=SKIndex_search`. You never set what `____` is equal to. Pretty simple.

Comment: Hi Charlie. I've replied in chat, but I'm not sure SO will notify you

Comment: Chat has to be live. The comment I left right below that should answer your question tho.

Comment: Oh. Unfortunately I still don't understand what you meant by "You set "location"=locality, but you set ____=SKIndex_search. You never set what ____ is equal to.". So to fix this, what do I need to do? Do I need to change my "using" query, or do I need to change my schema?

Comment: If you can, join that chat link above. Or if not, can you join the Dynamoose Slack channel (link is in the repo README) and message me there?

Comment: Oh never knew that Dynamoose have it's own Slack Channel. I'll meet you there then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As descrribed in the [Dynamoose documentation](https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Condition#conditionwherekey), `where` takes in a key attribute. This key represents an attribute name (`SK`), not an index name (`SKIndex`).

Changing your code to the following should work.

```
new dynamoose.Condition().where("SK").eq(SKIndex_search).filter("location").beginsWith(locality);
```

You can also use the [`using`](https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Query#queryusingindex) function to manually set a specific index to run your query on. However this is optional. Dynamoose will use a system to look through your indexes and pick one that best matches your query you are making.